# Android import java.nio.file.Files; cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, java-7

I am trying out the new Gmail API and the samples use the classes in the java.nio.file package, e.i. `Files` and `FileSystems`.

These classes was introduced in Java jdk 1.7 for the record, and since I am running jdk 1.7.0_65 in my Android app I have no idea why Android Studio cannot find these classes.

The imports are:

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
```

My build.gradle file of course tells the system to use v. 1.7 like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

I am pointing to the right directory of the jdk:

[image]

The jdk is listed in the External Libraries section:

[image]

And if I browse through the Java files I can even find java.nio.file.Files and .FileSystems:

[image]

**Now, what the **** is going on!? From my understanding I am doing everything right here, any suggestions?**

Comment: Man! I am having the exact same issue! What was your work around for doing what we _should_ have been able to do with `Files`? Any good third-party libraries? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your fine analysis! It's rare to see.

Comment: ok, but it still issue... Who know which kind of library we should use instead of?

Comment: Try using methods like `java.io.File.mkdirs()`, etc.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Android does not offer all classes that "conventional java" has to offer. `Files` is one of the classes, that Android doesn't offer.

You can have a look at the classes available in Android here: http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html

So unfortunately you have to use other functions / classes to implement the same functionality.

**PS:** The class is shown in your screenshot because you browse the classes of java installed on your **PC**, not those that are be available on the Android phone / tablet.

#### Update

The `Files`/`FileSystem` classes have become available starting with API version 26.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Not what I really wanted to hear, but that definitely clears up the enigma. thanks

Comment: ok, but it still issue... Who know which kind of library we should use instead of?

Comment: `java.nio.file.Files` is now in the link you provided, added in API level 26.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently `java.nio.file` is coming with Android O.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a Look of this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html) Android support some classes of NIO packages not full classes. But if you need to fast-up your code you can also use apache-commons api for the same.