# how to get path object in android

Tags: android, path, lucene

Iam using lucene in android.i could not import java.nio.file.Path package

```
import java.nio.file.Path;//this is not resolved in android studio


 //Creating an   internal dir;
 File mydir = this.getDir("my_dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

        if(!mydir.exists())
        {
            mydir.mkdirs();
        }
        Path dirPath = mydir.toPath();
        Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(mydir);
```

Iam using lucene 5.2.1
For FSDirectory.open() parameter to be passed  is of  type Path...so how can i get path object of the directory mydir that i have created

Comment: `java.nio.file` does not exists in Android SDK. `Path` should be either a regular `File` or a `String` path. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html

Comment: but FSDirectory.open() only takes path object...i cant send obj of type string or file

Comment: Then you simply cannot use `FSDirectory.open()` since it's dependencies are not filled.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene 5.0 to 5.2 won't work on Android, which I suppose they may fix in 5.3 or perhaps later.

Lucene 4.x works if you're persuasive enough, and [René Treffer has a simple app on github](https://github.com/rtreffer/ContactMerger) that shows how to win Lucene's heart. You may prefer to use [pickFirst rather than exclude in build.gradle](https://github.com/rtreffer/ContactMerger/blob/master/build.gradle#L46-48), depending on what your code needs to do.

Answer (score -1):

Android doesn't offer the class you need.

If you want to see what classes you can use, take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html

You have to use other functions.

If you want to know more about your problem, read  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24869904/4968143