# Tinify API with Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use tinify compression API in Android? I've implemented all the required stuff, but the app is crashing all the time. Here's the code:

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageName()+".jpg");
    try {
        Log.d("TINY", photo.getAbsolutePath());
        Source source = Tinify.fromFile(photo.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TINY", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A am getting the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.Paths

If it's not possible, are there any other good APIs for image compression for Android?

Comment: I've read the other question. But I cant fix my problem, does this mean that I cant use tinify in android?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as-is. Note that `java.nio.file.Paths` was added in Java 7, but Android still only fully supports Java 6, with [some Java 7 language features](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7) if you are using a specific `buildToolsVersion` and `minSdkVersion`. Also see the [Things that don't Work](https://github.com/yareally/Java7-on-Android#things-that-dont-work) section at the Java7-on-Android project page.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer to [Android import java.nio.file.Files; cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869323/android-import-java-nio-file-files-cannot-be-resolved) states, it's not possible to use classes from the `java.nio.file` package.

But that doesn't necessarily mean you can't use the Tinify API. If you're able to provide all other referenced classes, you can use it with a few modifications, since it's [open source](https://github.com/tinify/tinify-java) and there are only two occurrences of `Files` and `Paths` you need to rewrite:

[*Result.java*](https://github.com/tinify/tinify-java/blob/052caf40504ac8b7ce1b9f8352ce6538f29b8998/src/main/java/com/tinify/Result.java)

```
public void toFile(final String path) throws IOException {
    Files.write(Paths.get(path), toBuffer());
}
```

[*Source.java*](https://github.com/tinify/tinify-java/blob/44a15ccef74ff629ece022b3f372f36832a0b50b/src/main/java/com/tinify/Source.java)

```
public static Source fromFile(final String path) throws IOException {
    return fromBuffer(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
}
```