# How do I check if a File is a symbolic link?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an Android app that interacts with the file system of a device, and I need a static utility method to occasionally check if a [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object is actually a symbolic link to a different location.

I suppose the most obvious solution would be to use a method from the standard Java library such as [`Files#isSymbolicLink()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path)), but unfortunately this method does not exist in the Android SDK as explained in [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869323/android-import-java-nio-file-files-cannot-be-resolved).

Is there a reliable way to check if a [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) is a symbolic link or just a regular file?

Comment: My bad, this question is indeed a duplicate. The suggested links do help though, thanks!